# Custom Matlab DFT result is different from FFT

Tags: matlab, fft, dft

```
N=160; % No of Sample
for k = 1 : N
  dft(k) = 0;
  for n=1: N
    dft(k) = dft(k) + x(n) * exp(-1j*2*pi*(n-1)*(k-1)/N);
  end
end
```

Before implement this DFT, I had create a 160 sample sinusoid with 10 cycles using the following:

```
for n=1:160
x(n) = sin(2*pi*10*n/160);
end
```

When using fft():

the result of xfft(2) is -1.6580e-15+9.8769e-15i

but, the result of dft(2) is -1.2262e-15 + 9.5732e-15i

The results should be the same, but I cant figure out where is the problem....

Thanks

Comment: The results are equivalent to machine precision: see [this blog post by Loren](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/08/23/a-glimpse-into-floating-point-accuracy/).

Comment: In general I compare whether two numbers `x` and `y` are equal to machine precision like so: `areEqual = abs(x - y) / abs(x) < eps(1) * 1000`, where that magic number `1000` says that `x` and `y` can be considered equal to a thousand times machine precision `eps(1)`. Numpy provides an [`isclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) which I ported to [matlab](https://github.com/fasiha/personal-matlab-namespace/blob/master/%2Barf/isclose.m).

Comment: I was just thinking they should be absolutely the same. But I agree with you, thanks.

Comment: They won’t be the same because the FFT is a divide-and-conquer algorithm and can be shown to have better error accumulation properties than the direct method of evaluating the DFT (like yours). “Better” meaning the FFT will have less error than the direct DFT method—you can see why by remembering that in general, adding `N` floating-point numbers incurs RMS error of `sqrt(N)` so adding `log(N)` numbers, like FFT does, incurs `sqrt(log(N))`, much smaller. (See [Kahan’s summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) for a nice discussion of error growth.)

Comment: In addition, it can be shown that because of the way the FFT combines those `log(N)` numbers to produce a single element of the output, the error growth is even better.

Comment: Also, instead of your for-loop to produce `x`, just do `x = sin(2*pi*10* (1 : 160) /160);`. Note that [FFT](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html#buuutyt-6) is defined for sinusoids with time indexes running from `0 : (N - 1)`, not `1 : N`. If you run into unexpected problems, that’d be one thing to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Compared to the amplitude of your sinewave, anything e-15 (or e-15i) is essentially zero (numerical noise).  Thus 0 == 0, and your results are no different.